# Tomcat 7 - Maven Plugin?

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, tomcat7

I just wanted to double-check, has anyone found or is working on a Tomcat 7 plugin?  If not, is anyone interested in helping me get it up and running?

I want another quick alternative to Glassfish, JBoss AS 6.0 is a bit heavy still for quick mockups.

Walter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is [t7mp](http://code.google.com/p/t7mp/) - a Tomcat 7 Maven Plugin - on Google code.

[Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/) (and its Cargo Maven2 Plugin) also has support for [Tomcat 7](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Tomcat+7.x) (this was [CARGO-790](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/CARGO-790)).

[Apache Tomcat Maven Plugin 2.0-beta-1](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2/) supports Tomcat 7.

Comment: I am aware of Cargo, I still prefer the embedded version though.  I will check out the t7mp plugin, it looks like what I'd want.

Comment: I created http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MTOMCAT-62 for the "Maven 2.x Tomcat Plugin"

Comment: Apache Tomcat Maven Plugin 2.0-beta-1 supports Tomcat 7 :) http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2/

Comment: This might be the correct URL for the above 404d ones: 

https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-beta-1/

Comment: I must add that it works perfectly (2.0-beta-1, I mean). It even worked with my realms, which was my main concern.

Answer (score 41):

It work for me as the following.

My setting.xml

```
 <server>  
   <id>local_tomcat</id>  
   <username>ray</username>  
   <password>password</password>  
 </server>
```

My plugin configuration

```
 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
     <server>local_tomcat</server>  
     <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>  
  </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

My tomcat-users.xml

```
 <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <user password="password" roles="manager-gui, manager-script" username="ray"/>
```

Comment: Yes, that works. I was also struggling with this, but the URL configuration was what I needed. Seem to think Tomcat 6 was `http://localhost:8080/manager`, while Tomcat 7 is `http://localhost:8080/manager/text`

Comment: The URL ending in /text didn't work for me, I had to use /html to deploy remotely. I'm not sure why -- the Tomcat documentation seems to be in favour of the /text one.

Comment: I had to have the path in the configuration for it to work as well. <path>/myWebApp</path>

Comment: The URL ending of /manager/text worked with tomcat 7 for me. With /html it didn't.

Comment: Agree, but would use tomcat6-maven-plugin or tomcat7-maven-plugin.

Comment: manager-script role is for /text url; manager-gui - is for /html

Comment: For me works `/text`, I have set `manager-gui` and `manager-script`. I spent a lot of time with solving this problem. I have Tomcat 7.0.39

Answer (score 14):

i use the official **Tomcat7 Maven Plugin** from Apache as follows:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/${project.artifactId}</path>
                    <port>8080</port>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

and to run it: `mvn tomcat7:run`

Comment: mvn tomcat7:run is what no-one seems to mention, I was running mvn tomcat:run which starts up Tomcat6 even though I haven't specified the tomcat6 plugin anywhere.

Answer (score 7):

Using maven cargo your can coufigure your project that way :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <container>
            <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
            <type>installed</type>
            <home>${catalina.home}</home>
        </container>
        <configuration>
            <type>existing</type>
            <home>${catalina.home}</home>
        </configuration>
        <deployer>
            <type>installed</type>
            <deployables>
                <deployable>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                    <type>war</type>
                </deployable>
            </deployables>
        </deployer>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

don't forget to configure your `catalina.home` property

The you can deploy it using:

```
mvn cargo:deploy
```

Answer (score 7):

There is the [Tomcat Maven Plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html) 7 plugin developed by the Apache Tomcat team.

Currently you have to checkout the sources and install it to your local repository.
After that you can use it in the plugin section of your pom:

```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>start-tomcat</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                  <path>/</path>
                  <serverXml>src/main/tomcatconf/server.xml</serverXml>
                </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Answer (score 5):

After I had this error for three days in a row, here's my solution:

The user you are using to connect needs at least the role manager-script.
In your /conf/tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="test" password="test" roles="manager-script"/>
```

In your pom.xml, include the following plugin

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <url>http://server.url:8080/manager/text</url>
        <path>/YourApp</path>
        <username>test</username>
        <password>test</password>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Contrary to what I found in the internet you DON'T need to edit your maven setting.xml. The tomcat7-maven-plugin can be configured directly in the configuration-tag

A word to the url-tag: I tested the suffix

- /manager
- /manager/html
- /manager/text

of which only /manager/text worked

My versions:

- Tomcat: 7.0.33
- Maven: 3.0.4
- tomcat7-maven-plugin: 2.0
- Java: 1.7.0_07

Answer (score 2):

I'm using tomcat7-maven-plugin for my embedded tomcat instance. Here is how I have configured it. Since my app requires jaas authentication I can also provide that in the setting itself.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <!-- http port -->
        <port>8080</port>
        <path>/gcs-explorers</path>
        <contextFile>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml</contextFile>
        <addWarDependenciesInClassloader>true</addWarDependenciesInClassloader>
        <systemProperties>
            <java.security.auth.login.config>${basedir}/conf/jaas.config</java.security.auth.login.config>
        </systemProperties>
        <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/html</url>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>admin</password>
        <addContextWarDependencies>true</addContextWarDependencies>
        <addWarDependenciesInClassloader>true</addWarDependenciesInClassloader>
        <configurationDir>${basedir}</configurationDir>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.package.jaas</groupId>
            <artifactId>gcs-jaas</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.gcs</groupId>
            <artifactId>package-file-share</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the standard plugin works for me . I just had to create the role manager-script in tomcat users and change the url parameter to `http://localhost:8080/manager/html` in order to make it work :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
        <server>local</server>
        <path>/${project.artifactId}</path>
        <update>true</update>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

For Tomcat 7,

Step 1:
Modules tab of server add

```
Document base: <PATH>\Apache-Tomcat-7.0.0\webapps\manager
Path: /manager
```

Step 2:
Update POM to:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
          <update>true</update>
                <warFile>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.war</warFile>
                <path>/${project.artifactId}</path>
                <username>tomcat_user</username>
                <password>tomcat_password</password>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```