# In Grails, the command "tomcat:deploy" does not generate the complete war as the command "dev war" does

Tags: maven, grails, grails-plugin, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

The command **"grails dev war" deploys perfectly** in my local Tomcat6 server with a generated war which contains the next folders:

```
css
images
js
META-INF
plugins
WEB-INF
```

Unfortunately, I need that the command **tomcat:deploy** works too (I'm actually using: tomcat:redeploy -DskipTests). But Tomcat **gives the next error**:

```
2013-05-23 05:12:53,094 [http-8080-4] ERROR digester.Digester  - Parse Fatal Error at line 1 column 1: Final de archivo prematuro.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/Alojamiento/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Final de archivo prematuro.
    at
```

I added an **empty web.xml** in order to maven compiled. It is also empty in the generated war. So it is probably the cause of the problem ("grails dev war" generates a web.xml with code). Futhermore, the generated war only contains the next folders:

```
META-INF
WEB-INF
```

To be able to use "tomcat deploy", I added the next code to the pom.xml (after adding pom true, running "create-pom group" and other configuration changes):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager</url>                    
        <server>TomcatServer</server>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**UPDATE 1**
My full pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>alojamiento.ingenierosIW</groupId>
    <artifactId>Alojamiento</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>Alojamiento</name>
    <description>Alojamiento</description>

    <properties>
        <grails.version>2.2.2</grails.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
            <artifactId>grails-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${grails.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
            <artifactId>grails-test</artifactId>
            <version>${grails.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
            <artifactId>grails-plugin-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${grails.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.25</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>

    </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>${grails.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>resources</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.RC2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>db-reverse-engineer</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>database-migration</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement />

        <plugins>
            <!-- Disables the Maven surefire plugin for Grails applications, as we have our own test runner -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>surefire-it</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>plugins</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*</include>
                            </includes>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
                <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${grails.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Whether for Fork a JVM to run Grails commands -->
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>


             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!--<ignorePackaging>true</ignorePackaging>-->
                    <addContextWarDependencies>true</addContextWarDependencies>
                    <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager</url>                    
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <!--<username>admin</username>-->
                    <!-- <password>password</password>-->
                    <!-- <path>/u74937912-practica-WAR</path>-->
                </configuration>
          </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>grails</id>
            <name>grails</name>
            <url>http://repo.grails.org/grails/core</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>grails-plugins</id>
            <name>grails-plugins</name>
            <url>http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>tools</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>java.vendor</name>
                    <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                    <version>${java.version}</version>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                    <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you post your full pom? It sounds like the tomcat plugin for maven is using the WAR artefact generated by maven instead of the one generated by the grails plugin (which I assume you have configured in your pom?)

Comment: I updated it with the pom.xml (UPDATE 1). How could I configure it? I actually tried to find out in google with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly working with this:

**CONFIGURATION**

Previously, if you are using Eclipse with the plugin m2e, here is explained how to configure Eclipse in order to use Tomcat with it:
[tomcat-maven-plugin: Server returned HTTP response code: 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858436/tomcat-maven-plugin-server-returned-http-response-code-403)

Now, we need a proper settings.xml in the C:\Users\user.m2 with the same user and password than tomcat-users.xml. Then, we need to have our **pom.xml** configurated as follow:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>


<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager</url>   
    <!-- The next server must be the same than the one in settings.xml (at C:\Users\user\.m2): -->
    <server>TomcatServer</server>
</configuration>
</plugin>   


<plugin>
    <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
    <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${grails.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>init</goal>
                <goal>maven-clean</goal>
                <goal>validate</goal>
                <goal>config-directories</goal>
                <goal>maven-compile</goal>
                <goal>maven-test</goal>
                <goal>maven-war</goal>
                <goal>maven-functional-test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

**MAVEN COMMANDS TO DEPLOY:**

The next command get the configuration values of our database from datasource.groovy - production environmnent:

- tomcat:redeploy
- tomcat:redeploy -DskipTests
- grails:war tomcat:redeploy -DskipTests

To get the values from the development environment, the commands are the next:

- grails:war tomcat:redeploy -Dgrails.env=development grails:war
- tomcat:redeploy -Dgrails.env=development -DskipTests

Note1: if we not add -DskipTests (to no running tests before to deploying), and some test fail, it won't deploy.

Note2: in eclipse (with the plugin m2e for maven installed), you have to type these commands in the next field:

- Run - Run Configurations - Maven Build - Goals

**UPDATE 1**

Do not forget to create an empty web.xml under src/main/webapp/WEB-INF!

**UPDATE 2**

Do not forget to tell Grails to use the pom.xml: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Command%20Line/create-pom.html

Comment: I think the key part is binding the Grails plugin to the maven-war phase. You should accept your own answer as it's a good reference for the correct config for the grails plugin.

Comment: Sure! But I have to wait 17 hour for that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mvn grails:war tomcat:redeploy -DskipTests
```

That should hopefully get grails to attach the correct WAR artefact to the build so that the empty default one is not uploaded.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately the same error happens and the generated war looks the same.

Comment: maybe I have to configure manually tomcat-maven-plugin to include everything in the war?