# The command "grails tomcat deploy" produces "Error : java.net.HttpRetryException"

Tags: tomcat, grails

I added, in Config.groovy, my user and password of my local Tomcat server:

```
 tomcat.deploy.username="admin"
 tomcat.deploy.password="password"
 tomcat.deploy.url="http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text"
```

This is the error:

```
| Done creating WAR target\Alojamiento-0.1.war
Deploying application /Alojamiento to Tomcat
| Error : java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
```

If I run "grails dev war", I generate a perfect war, I can deploy it manually in Tomcat6 or Tomcat7. This question is probably related: [the command "grails run-war" throws Error java.lang.NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593443/the-command-grails-run-war-throws-error-java-lang-nullpointerexception)

Comment: Why is Tomcat Manager URL used to deploy your app? App should be deployed in the root context.

Comment: With other no grails project, I had to add "manager/text" to deploy. It deploys to the root context with "manager/text" included in the URL. (For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858436/tomcat-maven-plugin-server-returned-http-response-code-403)

Comment: Anyway, it returns now: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/deploy?path=%2FAlojamiento
So it looks that it is ignoring the line: tomcat.deploy.url="http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/"

Comment: Anyway, it must work with mv maven:deploy. But so far it didn't work either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705243/in-grails-the-command-tomcatdeploy-does-not-generate-the-complete-war-as-the

Comment: Was this ever resolved?  I'm having the same problem now with `grails prod tomcat deploy`