# Spring roo Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused: connect

Tags: spring, tomcat7, spring-roo, spring-tool-suite, maven-tomcat-plugin

I have a problem deploying my **Spring Roo** application with Maven, using **Spring Tools Suite 3.5.1** . I've been reading posts like this [tomcat-maven-plugin 403 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410479/tomcat-maven-plugin-403-error) but I continue with the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy (default-cli) on project prueba: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]
```

I'm running the maven doing this:

Right click over the project => Run as => Run configurations => New Maven Build => Goals: tomcat7:deploy

I've set my config files like this:

**pom.xml**

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>tomcat</server>
                <path>/prueba</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**tomcat-users.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-script,manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

**settings.xml**

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>myserver</id>
      <username>tomcat</username>
      <password>s3cret</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

Some posts are in controversy because of this line

```
<url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text</url>
```

They say I have to put **html** instead of **text** but It doesn't works and I can't rid of this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you install manager app properly on your tomcat? What's the content of you webapps dir?

Comment: The tomcat was bundled with the Spring Tool Suite, I didn't install anything else. I can't find where is the webapps dir using maven tomcat 7 plugin, can you tell me where to find the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve this error. I followed the last steps from [this blog](http://tomcat-configure.blogspot.it/2014/04/tomcat-maven-plugin-tutorial.html) and my working files have the following content:

**pom.xml**

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/ssigdl</path>
                    <update>true</update>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <username>tomcat</username>
                    <password>tomcat</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Note the password and username are exposed here so I removed the settings.xml file. When you don't want to expose these data you can create the **${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml**,

**tomcat-users.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="tomcat"></role>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"></role>
    <role rolename="manager-script"></role>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"></role>
    <user password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager-gui,admin-gui,manager-script"
        username="tomcat"></user>
</tomcat-users>
```

I just ran the maven command **tomcat7:deploy**

**IMPORTANT:** Don't forget to start the **VMware vFabric tc Server Developer Edition (Tomcat)** before running the maven command. I believed the tomcat7:deploy command started the server and then try to deploy but you have to start manually the server to deploy succesfully.