# Eclipse WebApp deploying over Maven with Tomcat results in Error: 'Failed to deploy application at context path'

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, deployment, maven

When I try deploying my **HelloWorld** project as describet at [IBM Developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-tomcat/index.html) to Tomcat 7 with Maven 3 using the command `mvn tomcat:deploy` I get the error `Failed to deploy application at context path /server`.

In the listed applications my /server appears but it can't be started.

I modified my maven web project according to the tutorial at [base22](https://wiki.base22.com/display/btg/How+to+create+a+Maven+web+app+and+deploy+to+Tomcat+-+fast) and applied the fix `<url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>` for Tomcat 7 deployment in the pom.xml as descibet at [loquatic](http://www.loquatic.com/wordpress/?p=126).

**The command:**

```
mvn tomcat:deploy
```

**The error:**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project server: Cannot
invoke Tomcat manager: FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path /server -> [Help 1]
```

**Tomcat tomcat-users.xml**

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager,admin-gui,manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

**Project web.xml**

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
  com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>sample.hello.resources</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**The error with -e:**

```
PS C:\Users\Dom\work\server> mvn tomcat:deploy -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.elexess:server:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 58, column 18
[WARNING] 'repositories.repository.layout' for maven-repository.java.net uses the unsupported value 'legacy', artifact r
esolution might fail. @ line 52, column 14
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building server Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) @ server >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ server ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ server ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ server ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Dom\work\server\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ server ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.2:test (default-test) @ server ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\Dom\work\server\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ server ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [server] in [C:\Users\Dom\work\server\target\server]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\Dom\work\server\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [85 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\Dom\work\server\target\server.war
[WARNING] Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored
(webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml attribute is specified as 'true')
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) @ server <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) @ server ---
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/server
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.017s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 14 08:00:14 CEST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/164M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project server: Cannot
invoke Tomcat manager: FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path /server -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1
:deploy (default-cli) on project server: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context pa
th /server

        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: FAIL - Failed to deploy applica
tion at context path /server

        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:145)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:70)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**Project pom.xml**

```
<build>
        <finalName>server</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                         <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
                         <server>mytomcat</server>
                         <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**Maven settings.xml**

```
<server>
        <id>mytomcat</id>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>admin</password>
</server>
```

Comment: Why does it say `[WARNING] Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored
(webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml attribute is specified as 'true')` and why would the web.xml be ignored?

Comment: How about posting the output running it with -e (stacktrace enabled)?

Comment: I modified the post and added the stacktrace as demanded

Answer (score 2):

For Tomcat 7 you need to deploy with the "text" URL. This URL is what is used by scripts to deploy.
You are trying to deploy with the "gui" URL.

Here's how to set it up:

**tomcat-users.xml**

```
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user password="script" roles="manager-script" username="script"/>
```

Then, in your pom.xml you set the URL to be: "http://localhost:8080/manager/text/"

Also, in your maven settings.xml, set your username/password to be script/script.

Answer (score 2):

I get this error,

```
  Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project projectname: 
Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: FAIL - Application already exists at path /path
```

Then I replaced the configuration from `mvn tomcat:deploy` to `mvn tomcat:redeploy`

Answer (score 1):

The application already exists at that location, you need to undeploy it first.

You can either undeploy it first using the tomcat manager or through maven using

```
mvn tomcat:undeploy
```

or use the following command:

```
mvn package tomcat:redeploy
```

to write over the current instance.

For more info look [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/context-goals.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I dont think this is the problem. I undeployed the application before I deployed again, also deploying with the error and then redeploying does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The tomcat [maven plugin usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/usage.html) page says that

> The default Tomcat manager URL is http://localhost:8080/manager.

I think you have to remove the `/html` part from your configuration.

Comment: As far as I am concerned this changed in Tomcat 7

Comment: In the [Tomcat 7 documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Supported_Manager_Commands) the path is `http://{host}:{port}/manager/text/`. It seems it has changed to `text`instead of `html`. See also this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714080/tomcat-7-maven-plugin/4553021#comment-5868038)