# Tomcat 6.0.32 + Maven undeploy via script not working

Tags: tomcat, deployment, maven, tomcat6

I'm using Tomcat 6.0.32 (with the new user management system (manager-gui, manager-script,...)), and I'm having some issues with the undeployment process using maven.

I keep getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:undeploy (default-cli) on project test: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: <html>
```

The issues seems to be with the tomcat target. Currently on my pom.xml I have this:

```
<configuration>
   <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
   <server>tomcat6</server>
   <path>/test/*</path>
</configuration>
```

I've read some issues with targeting /html or /text, but at this point I don't really know how should it work. /html is working fine for deploying (while /text is not), but not for undeploy.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I have moved to Tomcat 7.0.20, where the codehaus mojo mavent tomcat plugin works fine on both deploy and undeploy. But if anyone can solve the question out of curiosity ... :)

Answer (score 2):

To get both the tomcat:undeploy and tomcat:deploy to work I just had to add the role 'manager-script' to tomcat's tomcat-users.xml

Using the '/manager/text' url, I'm finally able to run them both. Without the role, I was able to run deploy and redeploy.

Comment: /manager/text is not working for me (with manager-script added to the user) on neither deploy nor undeploy. /manager/html at least lets me deploy.
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project tapmeme: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Ftapmeme&war= -> [Help 1]

Comment: /manager/text and manager-script works for me on Tomcat7 (not tomcat6).

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue. Remote deployment via the tomcat plugin for Maven did not work properly.

Thus, after applying the suggested approach of Matt, I agree that Tomcat6 and Tomcat7 **need different deployment-urls**!

For **Tomcat 6** it is:

```
http://%HOSTNAME%:8080/manager
```

For **Tomcat 7** it is:

```
http://%HOSTNAME%:8080/manager/text
```

For sake of completeness, it is also important that the user (defined in `%MAVEN_PATH%/conf/settings.xml` for the tomcat plugin) has the correct role (defined in `%TOMCAT_PATH%/conf/tomcat-users.xml`). The user requires to have the **manager-script** role.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember, the Manager App in Tomcat 7 in different to the previous one and the [Tomcat Maven Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3714080/696632) has no explicit support for. Check [this](http://code.google.com/p/t7mp/) instead.

Comment: "This Tomcat 7 Maven Plugin supports a full-featured Tomcat for testing (mainly integration-tests) with Maven. It supports multiple webapps deployed on tomcat."
As far as I understand, t7mp does not support remote deploying, does it?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Well, makes it pretty much useless.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still an issue, but in the interest of making it easier for folks that find this thread through google, I had a similar issue.

My fix for **tomcat6** was:

1. make sure the user had the `admin` and `manager` roles
2. for the URI use just `http://localhost:8080/manager` (i.e. - no "html" or "text" for t6)

I was using ant, though. But that being said, I think this will help for **tomcat6** regardless of build tool.