# configure eclipse, tomcat and maven to improve productivity in webapp

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, maven, build

(Am a maven noob)

Have a maven built webapp which uses spring, etc.

1. When I run "mvn clean install", it generates a .war file in the target directory.
2. I copy the .WAR file to tomcat for deploying the app.
3. Debug the app
4. Edit the code

This process takes a lot of time. When I earlier used ant, I would point tomcat's `server.xml` to my webapps directory. Also, Eclipse would put all of its classfiles in my `webapp\WEB-INF\classes` folder. If I had to modify any JSPs, I would just edit and there was no need of additional copying. If I modified a `.java` file, Eclipse would build it and put the `.class` file in the `WEB-INF\classes` folder so that Tomcat would pick it up.

Now, each time I make changes to a `.jsp`, I need to manually copy the `.jsp` to tomcat's webapps directory. Isn't there a way that a maven built app can optimize this process ?

So, where do you point your tomcat at that makes development productive?

```
project (where pom.xml resides)
  src
    main
     java
     resources
     webapp
       WEB-INF
  target
    webapp
    webapp.war
```

Basically, I would like to know how to configure eclipse(3.7.1) and tomcat/maven so that the edit/deploy/debug cycle is really fast.

**UPDATE1**

1) I was able to get m2e(http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/) installed in indigo(v. 3.7.1 of eclipse). it had 2 components 
a) maven integration for eclipse
b) slf4j logging

It installed successfully asking me to restart eclipse. I restarted.

2) Next, I installed m2e-wtp (at http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/)
It had 3 components 
a) maven integration for eclipse
b) maven integration for eclipse Extras
c) maven integration for WTP.

When I selected all 3, I got some error. So, I unselected the 1st two and only selected the 3rd one and then it installed successfully asking me to restart eclipse. I restarted.

@Raghuram
I ran the 4 steps that you suggested below. Only the 4th step resulted in an error and my webapp could not get deployed. It resulted in an error "File not found --- .svn/.wcprops/.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfZxm.png

What should I make of it ?

Thanks again,

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you to use cargo to deploy automatically to a local container (that can be downloaded and started) 
[Maven+Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin)

Then having that started with jpa activated (so that you can remotly debug your code) you just have to attach a listener and debug from eclipse, intellij, whatever.

For JSP, talking Intellij, you must tell your IDE where to package files (right-click 'package file") which is done in the project setup (output classes dir in WEB-INF/classes)

Check [Tomcat 7 - Maven Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714080/tomcat-7-maven-plugin) for an example cargo configuration for Tomcat 7. After the confiuration is valid you can deploy to your Container using `mvn cargo:deploy` and `mvn cargo:redeploy`

Comment: thanks. my target tomcat is tomcat 5.5. Also, 1) I want my JSPs to be copied to be available to tomcat whenever I make a change -- I don't want an additional deploy step. 2) when I make a java change, I want the class files to be "HOT" deployed/available to tomcat. How do I go about doing that ?

Answer (score 3):

If you use Eclipse Indigo with [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) and [m2e-wtp](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MECLIPSEWTP), you can pretty much develop and debug your web application without any manual step.

- Add tomcat as a server in Eclipse
- Import your maven project as a `maven project` in Eclipse.
- Build the project (using Eclipse or using maven)
- Choose "Run as server...".

Eclipse will pretty much take care of hot deploying jsps as well as classes on changes.

Comment: hi there, I got a fresh indigo (3.7.1). A) the m2e plugin went fine.  B) however, when i pointed eclipse to get the m2e-wtp(http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/), I got the following error : 1) the maven integration for eclipse was already installed 2) the m2e-slf4j over logback loggin -- was already installed