# Cannot invoke Tomcat manager

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I am trying to deploy my maven application on tomcat using

> mvn tomcat:deploy

and getting this error

```
  [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
```

In maven2/conf/setting.xml I have added

```
  <server>
   <id>TomcatServer</id>
   <username>tomcat</username>
   <password>tomcat</password>
  </server>
```

Inside tomcat-users.xml I have added

```
   <role rolename="admin"/>
   <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager-gui,admin"/>
```

Inside my pom.xml I put

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <path>/myproject</path>                 
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Even I tried to deploy the war using tomcat-manager. It deployes but does not start and when I start the the war it says

```
     FAIL - Application at context path /mywar.net could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/mywar.net]]
```

please let me know if you need more detail

Comment: Can you try running mvn tomcat6:run or mvn tomcat7:run  http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/run-mojo-features.html

Comment: Hi prashanth, I tried above commands and getting build error with The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-tomcat7-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found

Comment: You get this error because tomcat user doesn't contains a manager-script role. Try to add this role and rerun the command tomcat:deploy

Comment: maven-tomcat7-plugin does not exist means, that maven is unable to download from the repository. See these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714080/tomcat-7-maven-plugin and http://georgik.sinusgear.com/2011/11/13/apache-tomcat-7-maven-plugin/

Comment: Hi Skizzo, I added manager-script and run mvn tomcat7:run then its giving me error INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
Apr 08, 2014 10:34:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain.. I think its trying to run tomcat 6 instance

Comment: Hi Skizzo, sorry I used mvn tomcat:run then I am getting the above error

Comment: Hi Prashanth, I copied the plugin code from http://georgik.sinusgear.com/2011/11/13/apache-tomcat-7-maven-plugin/ but still I am getting same error when I run mvn tomcat7:run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user in your `tomcat-users.xml` should have `manager-script` and `manager-jmx` roles.
It also should not have `manager-gui` role, as this is for users that will use the tomcat manager website, instead of a script that will deploy automatically.