# tomcat-maven-plugin 401 . Error showing different port number

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I am trying to deploy a maven project in tomcat7 and getting this strange error:-

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project mywebapp: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=%2Fmywebapp&war=
```

The strange part is my server doesn't even run on port 8080,I use 8081. 
**This is the pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <warFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/${war.name}.war</warFile>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/manager/html</url>
            <server>localhost</server>
            <path>/mywebapp</path>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**settings.xml**

```
    <server>
    <id>localhost</id>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>password</password>
</server>
```

**tomcat-user.xml**

```
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="admin" password="password" roles="admin,manager-gui"/>
```

I have searched the net, made few changes accordingly ,but the error isn't going away.There are solutions for similar questions on the site, but they doesn't seem to work.
Can anyone tell me what is the problem here?
Thanks,

Comment: Check the server.xml of apache tomcat, and look for the connector port,it might be configured as 8080.

Comment: Nope, It is 8081. I have been using it for quiet some time now. Even so, the error should come up with 8081, if that was the case. I have the URL defined in POM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the wrong plugin is invoked. Your error message says "org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1" This is not the same as the tomcat7-maven-plugin in your pom extract.
Try to invoke this goal:

```
tomcat7:deploy
```

Comment: Yeah this seems to be one of the problems, the error has gone away, But another one came up: `Tomcat return http status error: 404, Reason Phrase: Not Found`.

Comment: I checked the tomcat logs : `"PUT /manager/html/deploy?path=%2Fmywebapp HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

Comment: @KanwaljeetSingh: Please accept the answer when it solved this problem and submit a new question with your new problem.  Did you try to add the role `manager-script` or the url **/manager/text**? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714080/tomcat-7-maven-plugin