# building maven project causing error

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

When I am deploying maven project using the command

> mvn clean install

I got the following error

> error :
>
> Failed  to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo: tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1 :
>   deploy-only (deault - cli) on project testapp : Cannot invoke Tomcat
>   Manager :  Server returned  HTTP response  code : 403  for URL :  http
>   : //localhost : 8080/manager/html/deploy?path=%2Ftestapp&war = ->

I changed the code in `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
<configuration>
  <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>   
  <warFile>target/testapp.war</warFile>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

when I changed the configuration  url

http://localhost:8080/manager/html

```
    chaned to
```

http://localhost:8080/manager/text

then my maven project was deployed successfully.

am I doing correct?

May I know the exact difference between them?

Thank You.

Comment: which version of tomcat?

Comment: I am using 7.0.42 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, maven is trying to invoke commands in tomcat.

Tomcat 7 provides separate manager roles for the GUI (`manager-gui`), status (`manager-status`), scripting (`manager-script`) and JMX proxy (`manager-jmx`), defined in `webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml`.

A user with role - `manager-script` can't use tomcat's `web-interface` ( i.e. `/html` URL of manager) while `manager-script` role is the one used by maven plug in.

So basically, you have to understand difference between Tomcat's `manager-script` and `manager-gui` manager roles. `/html` is not accessible for role - `manager-script` and only accessible for `manager-gui` role.

Coming to your original question, `/text` URL means that you are using tomcat's `text-based-interface` and `/html` URL means that you are using tomcat's `web-interface`.

Some additional information is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714080/tomcat-7-maven-plugin)

Comment: I clearly understand the difference between them. Thank You very much.

Answer (score 0):

The `/manager/html` path is the HTML interface to the Tomcat manager. The `/manager/text` path is the text based interface to the Tomcat manager that allows you to run commands such as deployments or reloads and considered the tools friendly interface. `/manager/text` is the path used by the Tomcat Maven plugin.

Comment: Thank you very much .  I clearly understand the difference between them